# multibox lightbox

Tags: javascript, multibox

I'm using [multibox 1.4 lightbox](http://www.phatfusion.net/plugins/multibox/) to show an enquiry form using PHP.

```
<a href="enquiry form popuppage link" class='mb3'  >
  <div align="center">
    <img src="images/sendenquiry.jpg" border="0">
  </div>
</a>
```

It opens the form to submit. The problem is I need to close the enquiry form, once after the `Thank you alert/print message` and not by using the existing close button.

Settings as follows:

```
var mb3;

window.addEvent('domready', function(){
    mb3 = new multiBox('mb3', {
        overlay: new overlay(),
        movieWidth:500,
        movieHeight:700,
    });

    var advanced = new multiBox('advanced', {
        overlay: new overlay(),
        descClassName: 'advancedDesc'
    }); 
});
```

Any one please help in this issue.

Answer (score 1):

If you are a fan of jQuery, you can use [Divbox](http://jquery.phpbasic.com/divbox) which is similar to Multibox.

In this lightbox, you can handle the close button.